# How do I find a synonym of a word or multi-word paraphrase using the gensim toolkit

Tags: python, nlp, word2vec, gensim, word-sense-disambiguation

Having loaded a pre-trained word2vec model with the gensim toolkit, I would like to find a synonym of a word given a context such as intelligent for 'she is a bright person'.

Comment: Your question is related rather to _paraphrasing_ or finding _paraphrases_ and not to synonyms. The difference is that two **words** can be synonymous but two sentences or a word and a sentence can be only paraphrases of themselves.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a method `[most_similar()][1]` that will report the words of the closest vectors, by cosine-similarity in the model's coordinates, to a given word. For example:

```
similars = loaded_w2v_model.most_similar('bright')
```

However, Word2vec won't find strictly synonyms – just words that were contextually-related in its training-corpus. These are often synonym-like, but also can be similar in other ways – such as used in the same topical domains, or able to replace each other functionally. (In that last respect, sometimes the highly-similar word-vectors are for *antonyms*, because words like 'hot' and 'cold' appear in the same places, referring the the same aspect of something.)

Plain word2vec also doesn't deal with polysemy (that a token like 'bright' is both a word for 'well-lit' and a word for 'smart') well. So the list of most-similar words for 'bright' will include a mix from its alternate senses.

Comment: I initially used the lesk algorithm (from nltk.wsd import lesk) but the results were not satisfying so I thought word2vec would be a better approach. Could you recommend me an alternative?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what the best practice is for synonym-discovery. (I could see word-vectors playing some role, but you may need other heuristics to confirm words are truly 'synonymous' from usage examples.)

Comment: There is some interesting work to tease out polysemy in word-vectors – see for example https://www.offconvex.org/2016/07/10/embeddingspolysemy/ or https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.06388 – and those plus something like the Lesk algorithm might help you determine when a word like 'bright' has multiple senses, and which sense is in use in a context. If you then look for most-similar words to that sense, you might have a higher proportion of synonyms (but still some intruding similar-usage antonyms or other related-words).